# Keycloak Javascript Policy based on resource info of realm

Tags: keycloak, policy, keycloak-authorization-services

I was searching through the supported policy types of keycloak, and saw that it offers some predefined choices regarding:

- Regex
- Role
- Client
- User
  ...
- Js

The most flexible one, seems to be Js after the [drop of support on rule based policies](https://www.keycloak.org/docs/latest/release_notes/index.html#keycloak-9-0-0).

So my question is, if it is possible to implement some type or parts of license enforcement using keycloak.

Say for example the case of denying access to a user if he/she is owner at more than **X** resources of a particular type. (E.g.  allow each user a limit of X image uploads). I couldn't find a way to implement this natively using the evaluation context. It might be possible by updating the permissions/scopes, such as removing a related user policy through an external service but it doesn't sound appealing. Is keycloak meant to support such a case through policies?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you explain more detail in this your statement? "he/she is owner at more that x resources of a particular type."

Comment: Hi, @BenchVue . Yes, I mean that, if a user of a particular realm is found as owner in let's say more than 10 resources of type image, I would like to be able to deny further requests on resource /image with post scope. Thus limiting a user's ability to upload more than 10 images in my application. For the resource definition and the mentioned field of owner, type see  https://www.keycloak.org/docs/latest/authorization_services/index.html#_resource_view

Comment: Thanks, Now I understood your request. I only experienced [time based policy evaluation](https://wjw465150.gitbooks.io/keycloak-documentation/content/authorization_services/topics/policy/time-policy.html), I have no idea how to evaluate to number of upload resource.